# Getting a specific page from Word

Tags: c#, office-interop

how to get specific page from word in c#.net console application?

I have tried it ,

But unfortunately I have got error from my application.

Following is my code:

```
{
object what = WdGoToItem.wdGoToPage;

object which = WdGoToDirection.wdGoToFirst;

object count = 0;

const string fileName = @"C:\..\..\test.doc";

object fileNameAsObject = fileName;

Application wordApplication = new Application();

object readOnly = false;

object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

wordApplication.Documents.Open(ref fileNameAsObject, ref missing, ref readOnly, ref missing,
ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);

// here on this following line I have got error "This method or property is not available because this command is not available for reading."
Range startRange = wordApplication.Selection.GoTo(ref what, ref which, ref count, ref missing);


object count2 = (int)count + 1;

Range endRange = wordApplication.Selection.GoTo(ref what, ref which, ref count2, ref missing);



endRange.SetRange(startRange.Start, endRange.End);
endRange.Select();

;
}
```

So please provide me any solution on it..
Thanks In advance..

Comment: Please give as much detail as possible for the error

Comment: Also what technology are you using here? There are the likes of [Open XML SDK 2.5 for Microsoft Office](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=30425)

Answer (score 5):

Are you using Office 2013? We ran into an issue with the same error message when running our interop code against a freshly installed Office 2013. It seems to be due to Office 2013's default "Reading Mode" as mentioned [here](http://www.dotnetmafia.com/blogs/dotnettipoftheday/archive/2012/10/03/how-to-disable-reading-view-in-word-2013-preview.aspx).

Try turning off the reading mode by setting `Application.ActiveWindow.View.ReadingLayout` to false (as mentioned in the comments of the article). This call must be performed after you have opened a document. Otherwise, the call would fail with the message: `System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException : This command is not available because no document is open.`

Answer (score 0):

After first call Word application still blocks document. Therefore document is read only.
Kill WINWORD.EXE process and then change code to:

```
Document document = wordApplication.Documents.Open(ref fileNameAsObject, ref missing, ref readOnly, ref missing,
                                                           ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                                                           ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                                                           ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
```

After work close document:

```
document.Close();
wordApplication.Quit();
```

After modifications working code:

```
        object what = WdGoToItem.wdGoToPage;

        object which = WdGoToDirection.wdGoToFirst;

        object count = 0;

        const string fileName = @"C:\..\..\test.doc";

        object fileNameAsObject = fileName;

        Application wordApplication = new Application();

        object readOnly = false;

        object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

        wordApplication.Documents.Open(ref fileNameAsObject, ref missing, ref readOnly, ref missing,
                                                           ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                                                           ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                                                           ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);

        // here on this following line I have got error "This method or property is not available because this command is not available for reading."
        Range startRange = wordApplication.Selection.GoTo(ref what, ref which, ref count, ref missing);


        object count2 = (int)count + 1;

        Range endRange = wordApplication.Selection.GoTo(ref what, ref which, ref count2, ref missing);



        endRange.SetRange(startRange.Start, endRange.End);
        endRange.Select();

        wordApplication.Documents.Close();
        wordApplication.Quit();
```

Comment: Are you kill WINWORD.EXE process before?

Comment: How it will be work? Actually I heard this kill WINWORD.EXE first time.And when It will be run and how?

Comment: Normally, `Application wordApplication = new Application();` starts new WINWORD.EXE process and `wordApplication.Quit();` closes it. Since you do not call `wordApplication.Quit();` at first time current frozen WINWORD process should be killed manually.

Comment: Hi, means Will I write code like this? Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document document = wordApplication.Documents.Open(ref fileNameAsObject, ref missing, ref readOnly, ref missing,
                                                           ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                                                           ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                                                           ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
            wordApplication.Documents.Close();
            wordApplication.Quit();

Comment: hi, Actually I am staring once again                       Application wordApplication = new Application() before the     Range startRange = wordApplication1.Selection.GoTo(ref what, ref which, ref count, ref missing);
            object count2 = (int)count + 1;
            Range endRange = wordApplication1.Selection.GoTo(ref what, ref which, ref count2, ref missing);
But now I have got error like "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."on this following line                        Range startRange = wordApplication1.Selection.GoTo(ref what, ref which, ref count, ref missing);

Comment: Where from wordApplication1? I have updated my answer with final working code.

Comment: Actually what happen.firstly I closed that wordapplication(),            Then I opened new  Application wordApplication1 = new Application() for Range.so that's why I took this wordApplication1.....and one thing My English is poor so Please try to understand.....Thanks

Comment: I have tried with your code but again I have got error on this line Range startRange = wordApplication.Selection.GoTo(ref what, ref which, ref count, ref missing);//"The RPC server is unavailable. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BA)"

Answer (score 0):

If you can I would use [Open XML SDK 2.5 for Microsoft Office](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=30425)

This gives you full access to the document and in my opinion is the most likely to work and not have any memory problems.

Answer (score 0):

I know its old but I didnt get a proper answer so my solution is here it works fine.

```
object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value; 
var document = application.ActiveDocument;
Word.WdStatistic stat = Word.WdStatistic.wdStatisticPages; 
int num =  aDoc.ComputeStatistics(stat, ref missing);    // Get number of pages

for(int i=0; i<num; i++)
{
    document.ActiveWindow.Selection           // Go to page "i"
            .GoTo(WdGoToItem.wdGoToPage, missing, missing, i.ToString());
    document.ActiveWindow.Selection           // Select whole page
            .GoTo(WdGoToItem.wdGoToBookmark, missing, missing, "\\page");
    document.ActiveWindow.Selection.Copy();   // Copy to clipboard

    // Do whatever you want with the selection
}
```